# Is it possible to include $math$ inside flextables?

Tags: r, math, r-markdown, flextable

I would like to have some fancy equations within a nicely formatted table. Is it possible to use flextable to achieve this?

```
library(flextable)
df <- data.frame(FancyMath= c("$A^{-1}$", "$A = pi~r^2$"))
flextable(df)
```

The $ $ notation is not creating Math-style writing as I would expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how your question is understood:

1. Is it possible to include $math$ inside flextables, i.e., math with LaTeX syntax, `$math$`?

No, it's not possible.

2. Is it possible to include "math" inside flextables?

Yes, what you are looking for is:

```r
install.packages("equatags")
library(flextable)

df <- data.frame(FancyMath = c("A^{-1}", "A = pi~r^2")) # Note `$` signs are omitted
flextable(df) |>
  compose(j = "FancyMath", value = as_paragraph(as_equation(FancyMath)))
```

Comment: `|>` is the base R piping operator (https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-native-r-pipe-98dea6d8b61b)